# Расчет чисел C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Не могу в С# разрешить такую ситуацию: рассчитал по определенным формулам три числа, записал их в листбокс так:

```
List<double> t = new List<double>() { x1, x2, x3 };

for (int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("x" + (i + 1) + " = " + t[i]);
}
```

А дальше мне нужно всегда произвольно выбирать два числа и на их основе вести расчеты дальше, а то одно число, которое не выбирается, тоже желательно куда-то записать... Помогите, пожалуйста, кодом, хотя бы примерным!

Comment: радномом из них выбирать 2 и храни линку на 3е...

Comment: можно кодом образец, я пытаюсь рандомом, но не понимаю как должно быть...из чего он должен быть: r.Next();

Comment: Вам надо случайно выбрать три числа или узнать что выбрал пользователь в листбоксе?

Comment: три числа я рассчитываю и из них случайно выбираю два

Comment: Выберите случайно одно, его и исключайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если случайно выбрать то можно таким образом (**Вот теперь работает**):

```
        var list = new List<double>();
        ...
        var rnd = new Random();
        list.Sort((a, b) => a-b==0? 0 : rnd.Next(-1,1));
```

и на выходе в листе у вас случайная последовательность чисел листа.

Можно сделать в том же ключе добавив случайные веса к списку и сортировать его:

```
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<double, int>>();
        ...
        var rnd = new Random();
        foreach(var val in list){ val.Value = rnd.Next(100); }
        list.Sort((a, b) => (a.Value-b.Value));
```

, но в Вашем случае ради трёх чисел смысла нету. Можно сделать так:

```
var list = new List<double>();
...
var list_rand = new List<double>();
var rnd = new Random();
while(list.Count>0)
{
   var i = rnd.Next(list.Count);
   list_rand.Add(list[i]);
   list.Remove(i);

}
```

Но как то сложно это для трёх чисел, так что лучше используйте исправленный первый вариант.

Comment: а вот это var list = new List<double>(); состоит из моих чисел?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: т.е.var list = new List<double>(){x1,x2,x3};
var rnd = new Random();
list.Sort((a, b) => rnd.Next(-1,1));
а что еще, так не работает, допустим когда я хочу вывести куда-нибудь два числа(

Comment: Эм, а что значит "Не работает"? Вывести два числа?

Comment: да, ошибка такая:
Не удалось выполнить сортировку, поскольку метод IComparer.Compare() вернул несовместимые результаты.

Comment: Да, логично :-) Сейчас ответ обновлю

Answer (score 2):

```
    int exeptIndex = new Random().Next(3);
    double exept = t[exeptIndex];
    t.RemoveRange(exeptIndex, 1);
```

Comment: это если одно убирать?

Comment: именно.....

Comment: а как вывести то число,которое убирается, скажем в label?

Comment: это exept.

Comment: вывожу я так: label11.Text = exept.ToString();
и скажем х1=1, х2=2, х3=3 и мне тогда все время выводится или 1, или 2, третий икс никогда не встречается...

Comment: поправил параметр Random.Next(3)